# How to compare two Time between Firsttime endTime with current time?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

Can any one describe me how compare two given time with current time?

I have Start time 11 AM  and End time 1PM. I have timer to tick only when time hour between 11AM to 1PM every day.

I have below code but its not working fine Please check.

```
TimeSpan StartHit = new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0);
TimeSpan EndHit = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= StartHit && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= EndHit)
{
     //my task here
}
```

Comment: If your code isn't work, please tell us _how_ it isn't working. You get any exception or error message, you get an unexpected result and so on.. _It's not working_ is the meaningless without any explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `13` as an hour, not `1` in your `EndHit`.

```
TimeSpan StartHit = new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0);
TimeSpan EndHit = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0);
if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= StartHit && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= EndHit)
{
   //my task here
}
```

[`TimeOfDay` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) represents the time interval that has elapsed **since midnight**. If you use `1` as an hour, it will be `1 AM` not `1 PM`.

And of course, a `TimeSpan` doesn't keep these values as `1 AM` or `1 PM`, these are just string representation of them. It keeps them as an integer values as `1` and `13`.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
TimeSpan EndHit = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0);
```

TimeSpan(1, 0, 0) is for 1 AM

Answer (score 1):

this code should be working fine:

```
 DateTime time1 = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime time2 = Convert.ToDateTime("11:00:00 AM");
 DateTime time3 = Convert.ToDateTime("1:00:00 PM");

 if (DateTime.Compare(time1, time3) < 0 && DateTime.Compare(time1, time2) > 0)
 {
 }
```

For example for DateTime.Compare(time1, time3), if Time1 > time3 it return 1, if time1 < time3 it returns -1 and if time1 = time3 it returns 0.
I hope this is helpful.